# Netmiko TEXTSFM Windows 10 issues

Tags: python-3.x, netmiko

I am running Python 3 on a Windows 10 computer.
When I run this it works fine.  When I add the `use_textfsm=True` to the results, I get a permission error where the templates are at.
Permissions seem to be fine. I would like to try copy the template folder to a new location but I am not sure how to tell netmiko the new location for that folder.

```py
from nornir import InitNornir
from nornir.core.task import Result, Task
from nornir_netmiko.tasks.netmiko_send_command import netmiko_send_command
from nornir_utils.plugins.functions import print_result

nr = InitNornir("h:/Scripts/IPvZero-master/nornir_textFSM_video/config.yaml")
results = nr.run(netmiko_send_command, command_string="show interface switchport")
print_result(results)
```

TextFSM Integration
Netmiko has been configured to automatically look in ~/ntc-template/templates/index for the ntc-templates index file.
Alternatively, you can explicitly tell Netmiko where to look for the TextFSM template directory by setting the NET_TEXTFSM environment variable
(note, there must be an index file in this directory):

```sh
export NET_TEXTFSM=/path/to/ntc-templates/templates/
```

Answer (score 0):

I already experienced the same issue in this environment.

**Environment**

```py
Python 3.9.4
testfsm==1.1.0
netmiko==3.4.0
```

The error message you got is the solution but you may have misinterpreted it. You should do the following:

1. Go to **Control Panel** > **View advanced system settings** and click on **Environment Variables**.
2. Under **System variables** <strike>(not **User variables** for username)</strike> click **New** and add the following variable:

   Variable name: **NET_TEXTFSM**

   Variable value: `%APPDATA%\Python\Python39\site-packages\ntc_templates\templates` (Validate the path does exist in Windows Explorer)
3. Restart your text editor.

If it didn't work, restart your PC and try again.

I already added this solution on [#1664](https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko/issues/1664#issuecomment-827141954)